# alternatives to jquery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On hover I want my div to scroll down.

I know i can use the `.animate({left: 0}, "slow");` but this doesnt go down but what else does jquery have to offer?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZvPk/4/

hover over the sectors box and you will see the "view project" move down. I need it to move down in a slow fashion similar to http://www.jeremymartin.name/examples/kwicks.php?example=3

Then need the opacity to be so my image is darker.

edit: slide down wont work with this:

```
 $(".sectorGrid").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children(".sectorImage").children(".showme").css("display", "block").css("margin-top", "-5px");
  },
  function () {
    $("div.sectorImage div.showme").css("display", "none");
  }
);
```

Comment: You mean something like `slideDown()`? I'm not sure I understand what you want, but if you need multiple transitions at the same time, `.animate()` is the only way to go.

Comment: i need soemthing thats going to slide down yes.. do you have an example of this slideDown?

Comment: `jQuery('div').slideDown('slow');`

Comment: `.animate` works by transitioning from the initial state of your object to the final state defined in the parameters. It sounds like you are assuming that `{left:0}` is the only option, but you can animate just about any CSS property which takes a numeric property. A slide down can be achieved by animating the height, for example.

Comment: could you guys provide an answer instead please. slideDown() wont work with my current code: see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want jQuery slideDown, see: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
Edit:
So something like this:

```
$(".sectorGrid").hover(
 function () {
    $(this).children(".sectorImage")
    .children(".showme")
    .css("display", "block")
    .css("margin-top", "-5px")
    .slideDown("slow");
},
 function () {
   $("div.sectorImage div.showme").hide();
 }
);
```

You could also, add a css class with the margin-top and display-block property, like:

> .slideDown { display: block !important; margin-top: 5px !important; }

```
/* !important so they won't be overwritten..*/
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$(".sectorGrid").hover(
 function () {
    $(this).children(".sectorImage")
    .children(".showme")
    .addClass("slideDown")
    .slideDown("slow");
},
 function () {
   $("div.sectorImage div.showme").hide();
 }
);
```

Comment: $(this).children(".sectorImage").children(".showme").css("display", "block").css("margin-top", "-5px").slideDown("slow")

Comment: i have other jquery which is adding inline styles. hence why i cant just slide it down.

Comment: Thanks but try the jsfiddle out. http://jsfiddle.net/WZvPk/13/ doesnt seem to slideDown

Comment: Not strange, since I only fixed sector 1 ;). Remove the inline css 'margin-top:-30px;' on the .showme divs

Comment: any ideas why the showme div is positioned to the right in IE7??

Answer (score 1):

What about css3 transitions? They are smooth and are starting to be widely supported.
[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/WZvPk/10/) which doesn't use javascript at all.

**Update** : [Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/WZvPk/12/) that doesn't use opacity.

Comment: Sorry i thought the solution that you did with css was not cross browser. If it is, then the first solution was perfect. WOW thanks for helping me think outside of the box.

Comment: It is NOT cross-browser. But, all the major (>75%) browsers support it (chrome,firefox,safari,opera and even IE10). From my experience, if a **new** feature doesn't work on an **old** browser, it will just encourage people to use a decent browser.

Comment: I 100% share your belief. But the customer will probably use IE7 and until IE 11 comes out, its going to be hell for me. :(

Comment: Sry, I didn't knew what kind of project this was. In this case, you should probably rely on jquery. Whenever I have a chance on a project, I try to explain the advantages of new technologies to the client, but he usually wants the site to work both on ie7 and iPhone 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".sectorGrid").hover(
  function () {
      $(this).children(".sectorImage").children(".showme").css("display", "block").animate({"margin-top": "-5px"}, "slow");

  },
  function () {
    $(this).children(".sectorImage").children(".showme").css("display", "none").css("margin-top","-25px");
  }
);​
```

Comment: thanks but when you hover a 2nd time the effect doesnt work, here is an updated jsfiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/WZvPk/8/

Answer (score 0):

​Now it works

```
$(".sectorGrid").hover(
  function () {
      $(".showme").css("margin-top", "-25px");
      $(this).children(".sectorImage").children(".showme").css("display", "block").animate({"margin-top": "-5px"}, 'slow');      
  }, 
    function(){
        $(".showme").css("display", "none")
    }
);
```

​

​